# Text hidden behind CSS border shapes

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a h1 style that is surrounding the text with a background color.

```css
    h1.skew {
        padding-left: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-top: 50px solid #4c4c4c;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <h1 class="skew">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zo32q98n/

At this point the text appears beneath the background. How can I make the text appear inside the brown colored background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the border is 50px tall, you can insert a negative margin of the same amount inside:

```css
h1.skew::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
h1.skew {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #4c4c4c;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
h1.skew::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="skew">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pseudo-element` for background and set `z-index: -1` so it appears under the text.

```css
h1.skew {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
h1.skew:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #4c4c4c;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="skew">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

```css
h1.skew {
  padding: 10px 80px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: #4c4c4c; /* fallback */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4c4c4c 80%, transparent 80%);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="skew">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively there is no problem if you use `border-bottom` instead of `border-top`.

```css
body {
    background: #ddd;
}

h1.skew {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;

  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #4c4c4c;

  height: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="skew">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text in a `span`...

```
<h1 class="skew"><span class="text">HELLO WORLD</span></h1>
```

And then add the following to your stylesheet...

```
span.text {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

This will move the text up so that it appears over the border you've defined.